# Do Swiss banks allow investigation of foreign embezzlement claims?

Tags: france, switzerland

There is reason to suspect someone who took a 91 year old French lady twice to Switzerland of embezzlement. The year after, she spent 50,000 on a veranda.

The old lady is thought to have had shares from her late husband, had a 15 minute short term memory. She didn't understand how the zeros work with currency denominations, 50 cents and 50 dollars were the same to her.

The trips to Geneva occurred on the in 2007, the veranda was bought in 2008, and Switzerland adopted transparency laws in 2017. I just became aware of the law change recently and am curious if it's simple to lodge a complaint.

Are the laws retroactive and do they address the given scenario?

Answer (score 1):

### All claims in Switzerland are statute barred after 10 years

So, whether the transparency laws are retroactive or not is irrelevant.